# Modify .bash_aliases with Python

Tags: python

So I've been trying to modify `.bash_aliases` programatically for a while now, and I've been running into issues with every method I've tried.

- Running my script using `sudo python3 myscript.py` causes the script to modify the `.bash_aliases` file of the `root` user. I can't find a way to determine what user ran the script to modify their file.
- Trying to use a shell command such as `sudo echo "my string" >> ~/.bash_aliases` gets an error: `sh: 1: cannot create /home/migue/.bash_aliases: Permission denied`, presumably because sudo can't display its password prompt when I call it programatically.
- I can't find a way to temporarily get root permissions after determining the full path (ie expanding `~`) of the file.

Basically, I'd love to know any reasonable method to modify and append to `.bash_aliases` through a Python script. I haven't found any questions on this where the solutions worked for me.

I'd prefer for this method to not require any non-standard modules, as installing them will just make the process less seamless for people who use the script.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't find a way to determine what user ran the script to modify their file.

You can reference the file `~/.bash_aliases` in your script and run it without sudo, unless your current user is root.

**EDIT:**
You simply need to add write privileges to `.bash_aliases` for every user it belongs to.

Comment: This doesn't help, since I need to determine the location of the file to modify it, then modify it. Determining the location with that method requires a non-root user, and writing to the file requires a root user. My problem is that I need both.

Comment: Then you should add write privileges to `.bash_aliases` for the current user. No need for sudo after that.

Comment: My script is simply supposed to add a simple alias, not change around all their settings. I want it to be a thing where someone can git clone my project, run the script to modify aliases, and then be done with it, without needing to go through all the trouble of modifying file permissions. Your solution doesn't answer my question. I need a way to get root privileges temporarily in Python in order to modify a file, where I need to know the location of it by having the file not be just run with sudo.

Comment: Can you try `sudo sh -c "echo 'text' >> path_to_bash_aliases"` instead of `sudo echo "my string" >> ~/.bash_aliases` inside your python script?

Comment: That one worked! Maybe submit a new answer with that one. If you can explain why it works, that'd also be great for anyone else that encounters this problem.

Comment: Ok slight issue. This method seems to remove all double quotes within my string. If my_str = 'some/directory/"with a"/space/in/it', then those quotes will be removed. Do I need to escape them more than once?